# select working on local host but not on internet

Tags: php

I designed a webpage that searches for answers to questions from a database and inserts more questions and answers to the database. it works perfectly on my local host but not on the internet, it successfully inserts data but doesn't seacrch for the data. the select query doesn't work, please what can be the issue

```
$question = strtolower($input);
            $question = str_replace('?', '', $question);
            $question = trim($question);
            echo "<br/>";echo "<br/>";echo "<br/>";echo "<br/>";echo                              "<br/>";echo "<br/>";echo "$question";
            print_r($result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM chatbot WHERE LOWER(question) like '%$question%'"));
            print_r($fetched_data = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
            $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
            $rand = rand(0, $row_cnt - 1);
            if ($row_cnt > 0) {
                return $fetched_data[$rand]['answer'];
            } else
                return "Am sorry, this question wasn't found,Please ENTER TRAIN:QUESTION#ANSWER#password to make me smarter";
```

Comment: What is the `error`?

Comment: `echo '<br/> br/> br/> <br/>';` will suffice. No need to call echo 4 separate times.

Comment: it doesn't show any error, it just jumps to the else part of row_cnt, but on my localhost it searches the database and brings results

Comment: no checking the error_log? No warning, notice, or error?

Comment: it inserts data but doesn't select data when i upload to the internet, but on my local host, it inserts and searches for data